# Perl error "Illegal octal digit '8'" when reading in URL

Tags: perl

I am trying to format a .txt file to fit the format my lab is using to upload data for a project. Within the .txt file are URLs that I am using as IDs for blog entries. However, when I pass them as STDIN to my Perl script I get this error:

```
Illegal octal digit '8' at Desktop/blog.txt line 3, at end of line
```

This is the URL it is failing on:

```
http://thealbinobean.blogspot.com/2013/08/we-are-all-miley-cyrus.html
```

I understand that the error occurs because Perl is interpreting the "08" as an octal number, but I can't figure out a way for Perl to interpret the entire URL as a string instead. Here is my code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $count = 0;
my $blogName;
my $entryID;

# desired format:
# {{ID=URL}}{{USER=BLOG NAME}}
# Blog entry on one line
# "<ENDOFBLOG>"

foreach my $line (<STDIN>) {
    if($count == 0) {
        $blogName = $line;
    } elsif($line =~ /^http/) {
        $entryID = $line;
        print "{{ID=$entryID}}{{USER=$blogName}}";
    } elsif($line eq "<ENDOFBLOG>") {
        print "<ENDOFBLOG>";
    } elsif($line !~ /^\s*$/) {
        print $line;
    }
    $count++;
}
```

Question: How do I get Perl to interpret the input as a string in order to avoid this octal interpretation?

Comment: String concatenation in Perl is done with `.`, not `+`.  Also, you need a `$` before each occurrence of `count`, `blogName`, and `entryID`.  The code you've posted won't even make it past Perl's compilation stage.  How about you post your real code instead?

Comment: And variables need sigils. `my count`, `my blogName` should be `my $count`, my `$blogName`. This is likely due really wrong syntax giving an error message because your source is being used in a different context than you think it is.

Comment: Man, I haven't coded in Perl in forever, I had no idea my code was so bad. Anyways, I fixed those errrors, but the bug still occurs.

Comment: We need to see the new code, not just a paraphrase of "I fixed those errors."

Comment: I edited the code above to reflect the changes I made in my actual code. I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @DigitalSea: You're still missing some `$`s.  It's also obvious that the code you're showing us isn't what you're running, as you'd be getting completely different error messages then.  *If you want us to fix your code, you have to show us your **real** code.*

Comment: It actually is my read code. For some reason, it isn't giving my compilation errors. This is my first time coding in Perl in months, so I understand the frustration you must be having correcting all my errors, but for whatever reason the only error I'm getting is the one posted above.

Comment: what line number is the error given for?

Comment: it sounds like you think you have made the same changes to your post that you have made to your real code; this is very error prone.  please copy and paste your actual code.

Comment: Perhaps the contents of blog.txt would be helpful for us to reproduce the issue. I can't figure out what you're operating on from that flow. However, you almost certainly need to `chomp` your lines to get rid of the trailing newline from what I see.

Comment: `at Desktop/blog.txt line 3`? line 3 is a blank line.

Comment: I bet a dollar that he's running the program like `perl urlList.txt program.pl` instead of `perl program.pl urlList.txt`, and that it manages to stumble through 3 lines of a text file parsing it as perl before running into something that makes it croak.

Answer (score 2):

Did you run your program? I was getting tons of compilation errors:

- You didn't use `my` in your `foreach` loop when declaring `$line`.
- You don't have sigils on your initial variable declarations.
- You are using `$_`, but aren't setting it anywhere.
- You're not printing any NL on your `print` statements.
- You are using `+` to concatenate your string. This is *addition*. You use `.` to concatenate

And, you don't even have to do that. Perl concatenates variables without a problem:

```
print "{{ID=$entryID}}{{USER=$blogName}}\n";
```

Get your program working. Fix these errors. Give us a bit more data to work with, so we can figure out what your program is doing.

---

## Addendum

> I don't understand why I'm not getting these compilation errors. Otherwise, I would've fixed all this stuff before submitting. Maybe it has to do with how I'm executing the script and feeding it input in Terminal, because the only error I'm getting is the one listed above.

Here's your ***original*** program:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my count = 0;
my blogName;
my entryID;

# desired format:
# {{ID=URL}}{{USER=BLOG NAME}}
# Blog entry on one line
# "<ENDOFBLOG>"

foreach $line (<STDIN>) {
    if(count == 0) {
        blogName = $line;
    } elsif($_ =~ /^http:/) {
        entryID = $line;
        print "{{ID=" + entryID + "}}{{USER=" + blogName + "}}";
    } elsif($line eq "<ENDOFBLOG>") {
        print "<ENDOFBLOG>";
    } elsif($_ !~ /^\s*$/) {
        print $line;
    }
    count++;
}
```

Here's the errors I'm getting:

```
No such class count at ./test.pl line 5, near "my count"
syntax error at ./test.pl line 5, near "my count ="
No such class blogName at ./test.pl line 6, near "my blogName"
No such class entryID at ./test.pl line 7, near "my entryID"
Global symbol "$line" requires explicit package name at ./test.pl line 14.
Global symbol "$line" requires explicit package name at ./test.pl line 16.
Global symbol "$line" requires explicit package name at ./test.pl line 18.
Global symbol "$line" requires explicit package name at ./test.pl line 20.
Global symbol "$line" requires explicit package name at ./test.pl line 23.
Bareword "count" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at ./test.pl line 15.
Bareword "blogName" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at ./test.pl line 15.
Bareword "entryID" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at ./test.pl line 18.
Bareword "entryID" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at ./test.pl line 19.
Bareword "blogName" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at ./test.pl line 19.
Bareword "count" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at ./test.pl line 25.
Execution of ./test.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Comment: I don't understand why I'm not getting these compilation errors. Otherwise, I would've fixed all this stuff before submitting. Maybe it has to do with how I'm executing the script and feeding it input in Terminal, because the only error I'm getting is the one listed above.

Comment: sounds like the problem is not your script but instead how you are running it (there's no way the script you show would even compile, much less produce that error).  update your question describing exactly how you are running your script.